# showing a alert/info message on salesforce standard page based on some condition

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am a beginner in Salesforce. I am trying to implement a code wherein user will get a alert message (some sort of notification ) when a field value is null. Although it will allow the user to save that record.
I wrote a VF page. that I will embed with the standard page layout.
Let me know if that is the correct approach.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" action="{!markread}" extensions="OppExtension">
<script>
      if(!Opportunity.Country__c != null {
          alert("Please fill in the country details");
      }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

and my extension controller:

```
public with sharing class OppExtension {
     ApexPages.StandardController controller;
     public OppExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
         this.controller = controller;
     }
     public void markread() {
         Opportunity o = (Opportunity) controller.getRecord();
         o.MessageShown__c = true;
         update o;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code, it will be easier for us to help you with it.

Comment: Code added in question section.

Comment: Here is an alternate suggestion from @crop1645 on a similar question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46361/soft-error-in-standard-salesforce-page.

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce page

```
<!-- Using java script in visualforce page -->
<apex:page extensions="OppExtension">
  <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
           Input Here  : <apex:inputText id="inptID"/>
                       <apex:commandButton onclick="MyjavaFunction('{!$Component.inptID}')" value=" Submit "/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>

  <!-- Java script starts Here -->
  <script>
   function MyjavaFunction(ReceiveInputID){

    var inputValue = document.getElementById(ReceiveInputID).value;
         if(inputValue == ''){
            alert('You did not eneter any value in input box');
         } 
         else
            alert(' You entered :: '+inputValue); 
   }
  </script> 

</apex:page>
```

Here is one code which may be useful for u

[image]

Comment: Hi, problem here is ..the layout where I am planning to add this logic is a standard object's page layout. so I am not sure how to use  "document.getElementById(ReceiveInputID).value" in this page since I do not know "ReceiveInputID"'s avlue here.