# Can we Display a Error Message on Standard Detail Page of Opportunity on Load

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity

I have a requirement on Loading Standard Opportunity Detail Page, if Opportunity Amount is greater than certain value say 500K i need to display a message on top of page. is it possible without performing any DML operations on the page to get the message. I thought of all possible ways but could not figure it out.

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46414/2602

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use a formula field located near the top of the page. Perhaps an image formula, so you could display caution symbol etc.

More info on it here:

[link](http://www.shellblack.com/administration/using-image-formula-fields/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript injected into the standard detail page via a button following this approach [Changing the color of a custom button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10516/changing-the-color-of-a-custom-button)

This method is a workaround and maybe not officially supported. But you can mimic the look&feel, placement and behavior of the message exactly as you require and you will have greater flexibility.

If the look&feel is not crucial you should prefer the method suggested by @DavinC