# VF Action to Redirect to a Standard Page with Custom Error Message

Tags: visualforce, error-messages, actionfunction, redirect

I have a VF page that produces an Excel file based upon certain products underneath an Opportunity. How would I go about using a VF action to redirect back to the Opportunity standard screen if no matching products were found and display a custom error message?

I can redirect back but I can't figure out how to display an error, for example like using `ApexPages.addMessage`

Here's my action/redirect code from my extension so far: `validOLIs` is a boolean which returns true if the product query returns 0.

```
//Action to highlight no OLIs were returned
public pageReference noValidOLIS(){
    if(validOLIs){
        return redirectError();
    }
    return null;
}

public PageReference redirectError(){
    PageReference errorRef = new PageReference('/'+theOpp);
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'No Products Found'));
    return errorRef;

}
```

Edit:
I've tried using addmessage and directing back to the standard page.  I'm open to using java script if it can be used to intercept, but I'm not a js expert so would need some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I took, feel free to shout me down if anything I've done here is bad practice! Seems to be working fine for me so far.

I created an execute javascript button (Opportunity detail page button) using the below:

```
var query = "SELECT Id, test__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' AND test__c = True"; 
var oli = sforce.connection.query(query).getArray("records"); 
if(oli=="") 
{ 
alert('No Items Found'); 
} 
else 
{ 
//redirect to VF page 
window.location = "/apex/VfPage?id={!Opportunity.Id}"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the Apex controller of the page where you are redirecting add the following logic in the constructor:

On redirect page:

```
public PageReference redirectError(){
    PageReference errorRef = new PageReference('/'+theOpp+'?showError=true');
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'No Products Found'));
    return errorRef;
}
```

Page where you redirect, add in constructor:

```
String showError = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('show_error');
if(showError=='true')
{
   ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'No Products Found'));
}
```

If you are redirecting to standard page then you won't be able to set error message.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear in my question that I had tried addmessage. I'm open to using java script if that is an option.

Comment: @Girbot you cannot show a error message on standard page. You can only show error on custom vf page. You can ake user 4-5 seconds on you vf page unit it shows a message then redirect the user to standard page.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to show error messages on Standard pages is to use the soft alert technique as outlined [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46414/2602)

basically, you are setting values in custom fields on the object and using a formula field on that custom object to display (with image flags), the error message. With clever use of formulas, you can even make the message disappear after a few minutes/hours - this requires timestamping a custom field with the error datetime